# Base64_encode and file_get_contents are not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why this code is not working in Codeigniter, while when I remove `base64_encode` the code runs perfectly and the same if I use `file_get_contents`, why both function are not working?

```
$imagedata = mysql_real_escape_string(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your PHP version and what errors do you get? What happens if you do this: `var_dump($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"])`?

Comment: nothing error displayed just blank the page when i click the submit button and my php version is 5.5.11

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is making error here . These two link will help you to handle this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602286/mysql-real-escape-string-errors) and [link2](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)

so please use `$this->db->escape($val)` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
 <?php
    // <= PHP 5
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], true);
    // > PHP 5
    $data = file_get_contents($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    ?>
```

`$_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]` produce file name like

```
<?php
// <= PHP 5
 $data = $this->db->escape(base64_encode(file_get_contents("test/faruk.txt", true)));
// > PHP 5
 $data = $this->db->escape(base64_encode(file_get_contents("test/faruk.txt", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH)));
echo $data; 
?>
```

and my output is `SGVsbG8gd29ybGQxNDEyMTYyMTYx` for content "Hello world1412162161"

Comment: i know this code is run perfectly but i want to include also base64_encode..i have a problem only in codeigniter,my code is run perfectly in core php

Comment: No it should not be. There is nothing of codeIgniter and no relation of codeIgniter here ,  mysql_real_escape_string is the issue here

Comment: dear i'm using in most of projects in core php and i remove mysql_real_escape_string to check the code but the problem is same, after submit the form page is blank..i don't know that relate to codeigniter or not but i getting problem in codeigniter so i ask..!

Comment: Please use $this->db->escape($val) instead of mysql_real_escape_string i am pretty sure it will help you

Comment: also have a same problem..i am using this code now
  $val = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']));
  $profile_img= $this->db->escape($val);

Comment: yup, and now i also find the problem,problem is that i am sending a form thorugh ajax so the problem is occur and here is the link to ajax that i use.. http://www.formget.com/ajax-image-upload-php/

Comment: You no need to do such thing , you just change filed type to longblob in db and  follow the link [here](http://pujanpiya.com.np/?q=node/25)