# Alternative to mysql_real_escape_string for PHP

Tags: javascript, php, sql-injection

Is there an alternative to mysql_real_escape_string for PHP.  I want to remove any javascript or php code entered into the text box.

Comment: strip_tags will be an option

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` is not designed for removing JS or PHP code ... What do you want to do? Escape data before putting in the database? Or strip JS/PHP code?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db

Comment: @AresDraguna I did contact Larry Page, who apparently is a very good friend of mine. He said though Google gives you results, its good if you get user-level which gives me more hands on.

Comment: @X10nD I don't care who your friends are, your question does not respect SO guidelines for asking questions and there are so many alternatives to `mysql_real_escape_string` that you can fairly call this an opinion based question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking for. It's going to be damn near impossible to filter out any PHP or JS code, but unless you're eval'ing it or putting it in <script> tags, it's not going to do anything. Just make sure you use htmlspecialchars when you print it to the screen. You should be doing this anyway.

Comment: @rjdown I dont want anyone entering any javascript or php code in a text box.  Ofcourse I could check on sql commands with mysql_real_escape.

Comment: @X10nD tell me... how come you have 4k rep and still don't know how to ask questions on SO?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not what mysql_real_escape_string does or did (the functions are now [deprecated](https://www.php.net/mysql_query)). An alternative to mysql_real_escape_string is using prepared statements, for example with [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/MySQLi).

However, that's completely unrelated to stripping Javascript or PHP code from a string - also; it could be relatively hard to identify 'Javascript'  or 'PHP'.

The real question here is; why do you wanna strip it? The danger doesn't reside in **saving** the data, the danger resides in **displaying** the data. You should never ever execute code entered by the user, be it Javascript or PHP.

As for Javascript, disallowing HTML tags in your output is enough. Look into functions as [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags), or even better, [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars). Preventing PHP from execution is even easier; just **do not** use the method [eval](http://php.net/eval).

Comment: So which is better htmlspecialchars or strip_tags?

Comment: It depends on your needs. strip_tags strips all tags (HTML and PHP), which leaves you with a malformed string. html_special_chars enables you to display user-entered data, without the risk of Javascript being executed.

Comment: So if I echo(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(string)); it might just work out good?

Comment: It's either htmlspecialchars() or strip_tags(). The combination is redundant. I'd go for htmlspecialchars().

Comment: why would it be redundant since each have different properties.

Comment: It's redundant in the sense that strip_tags isn't necessary if you use htmlspecialchars. htmlspecialchars may indeed still be necessary if you use strip_tags, because it escapes characters that have significance in HTML (such as '<', without it being part of a tag).

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` is a function that ensures that your string is correctly escaped for entering into the database. What goes into the database is exactly what you started with.

Anything that removes or changes the string will not be an alternative to `mysql_real_escape_string`. In other words, it will change the string, not escape it.

If you want to change the string you are storing, you can run it through `strip_tags`, or `preg_replace`.

But (if it's appropriate to your situation), consider instead running the string through `htmlspeciachars` after retrieving from the db, before displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string is used to avoid SQL injection attacks - where by people try to execute SQL commands against your database. **You still need to use this** - (or move to PDO prepared statements etc).

mysql_real_escape_string is not meant as a way to sanitize user input (e.g html, javascript) which would make your site open to XSS attacks. For that I would recommend [Html Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strip_tags()` - it will delete all html tags, including javascripts.

Comment: Can someone tell me, why the downvotes? He asked how to remove code from text, which is exactly what strip_tags does.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but I agree with them. strip_tags removes html tags. it doesn't remove javascript (unless it's in script tags), or php (even if its in php tags).