# output data from database using htmlspecialchars() that has been filtered using filter_input()

Tags: php, security, mysqli, xss, htmlspecialchars

I have found from different blogs that it is strongly recommended to use `htmlspecialchars()` to output any data on screen to be safe from `XSS Attack`.

I am using `filter_input()` to filter any data that comes from user before inserting into `database`. `filter_input()` convert special characters like `'` to `&#39;` and saved it that way,like

```
 I&#39;m going to shopping with Molly&#39;s sister;Dolly
```

.My question is

`How can I print(output) apostrope or quotes and specific special characters to users screen using htmlspecialchars so that the output would be user friendly`

I have tried to use `htmlspecialchars($post,ENT_NOQUOTES);`,but it gives me same copy of data that is stored in database.If I don't use `htmlspecialchars()`,just `$post` gives me expected result,which I think is vulnerable to `XSS Attack`

Thanks for your time,and look forward to get help from peers.

**EDIT**

I got suggestions to use `htmlspecialchars_decode()` or `html_entity_decode()` on answer,but 
([https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/ja͢ck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/ja%CD%A2ck))
and some other suggested not to use these `functions` to output data on screen.

Please be informed that I am using `prepared statement` and `parameterized query`.But I don't want to keep any security holes,that's why filtering data before sending into database.

As I have used `filter_input()` to filter data before sending to database,is it safe to output data directly(`$post=$posted_data;`) from database without using `htmlspecialchars`?

If I must need to use `htmlspecialchars` to output data,then how can I do it in this case?

**Code Sample**

```
 $stmt1=mysqli_stmt_init($connect_dude);

 /*Inserting into database*/

 if(isset($_POST['titlex']) && isset($_POST['pricex'])  && isset($_POST['detailx'])){
  $tit=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'titlex',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  $pri=preg_replace('#[^0-9]#','',$_POST['pricex']);
  $det=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'detailx',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

  $query2="INSERT INTO `hotel1`.`dine` (user_id,title,price,detail) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1,$query2);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "isis", $logged_id, $tit, $pri, $det);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);    
 }

 /*Get Data from DB*/

 $query1="SELECT id101,title,price,detail FROM `hotel1`.`dine` WHERE user_id=?";

    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt1,$query1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, "i", $user_idx);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt1);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt1, $id101, $title,$price, $detail);

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt1)){
     $id101=$id101;
     $title=$title;        //htmlspecialchars needed
     $price=$price;       //htmlspecialchars needed
     $detail=$detail;    //htmlspecialchars needed

     ........................
     ........................
     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am using `filter_input()` to filter any data that comes from user before inserting into `database`.

**This is a bad practice.** Do not mangle your data before you insert it into a database. It's 2015; don't sanitize, use prepared statements instead.

```
$db = new \PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase;charset=UTF-8',
     $username,
     $password
);

// other stuff in between

$statement = $db->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO yourtable (email, username) VALUES (:email, :username);"
);
$success = $statement->execute([
    ':email'    => $_POST['email'],
    ':username' => $_POST['username']
]);
```

**Prepared statements remove the need for `filter_input()`**. You're not adding defense in depth by doing this, you're just ruining data integrity and giving yourself a headache.

When you render your output, if you want to allow HTML, use [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Otherwise, use `htmlspecialchars($output, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8')` for best results.

Recommended Reading: [Web Application Security](https://defuse.ca/web-application-security.htm) by Taylor Hornby.

Comment: I am using `prepared statement` and `parameterized query` already.But I don't want to keep any security holes,that's why filter data before sending into database.

Comment: And,`HTMLPurifier` should be used for `textarea` where I want to allow limited `HTML Tags`.I am using `HTMLPurifier` for textarea,but not for text field.Because It's 2015.Thanks for your answer,dude.I really need an elaborate answer that would relieve all my confusion.

Comment: You should `htmlentities()` the contents of a textarea anyway. if you're using prepared statements, you don't need to sanitize your input. It separates data from instructions.

Comment: I just want to emphasize again that sanitizing for output is something you need to do __on output__, not when you insert it into the database. Sanitizing before insertion just leads to data corruption.

Comment: @SvenSlootweg did you mean to insert user inputted data as it is into database?And just use `htmlspecialchars` to output to users' screen. doesn't malicious data can be inserted even after using `prepared statement`?

Comment: What do you mean by malicious data?

Comment: @Coder Yes, that is what I mean. It isn't "malicious data" as long as it is in the database - the database has no idea what HTML or Javascript is, doesn't care, and so doesn't need to be protected from it. It's all just bytes, it could be *anything* as far as the database is concerned. XSS only becomes a problem when you try to *output* data into a webpage, and that's why you sanitize it *on output*. Just keep the original data in your database, so that you have 'intact' data to work from if you ever need to change anything.

Comment: I just want to keep it simple and don't want to allow any `html tags` for any field.

Comment: If you do that, it doesn't allow ANY tags. It turns `<` into `&lt;`, etc. according to the HTML5 spec. You're safe. https://eval.in/300124

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with your strategy.

You certainly need to filter input and output stuff but you're overlaying them - double escape.
The problem is your input filter is doing also the output filter's work.

> As I have used filter_input() to filter data before sending to database,is it safe to output data directly($post=$posted_data;) from database without using htmlspecialchars?

No. Don't trust your database, or at least not always. It wouldn't be the first case an SQL injection caused a huge XSS.

> If I must need to use htmlspecialchars to output data,then how can I do it in this case?

As I said above, stop using input filter for output filtering. Your input filter should just make sure the data is safe for internal use - to protect your application against not-indented operations. Thus you don't need to escape HTML before inserting to database, and as a bonus you'll save space.

On the other hand output filter cares about the end-user. You take the data from db and send it to the user. We're talking about `htmlspecialchars` which is fine with `ENT_QUOTES` but in my opinion is not sufficient. You should also escape characters like `(` `)` `[` `]` `=` `+` `-` `\` since there are cases you don't need for a successful XSS attack to open/end any tag or use quotes. For example when you output data into `onclick`, etc.

I just saw that `htmlspecialchars` has double_encode parameter, which would eventually solve your problem:

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8", false);
```

Doing this will always keep HTML special chars escaped and won't escape already escaped stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You want to go the other way around :) [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php)

Comment: But I was told `htmlspecialchars_decode` is a bad idea for outputting data.`XSS` risk

Comment: Ah, I understand now, my apologies. This is the "less bad" http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Comment: If you wan to handle it yourself to be extra "secure" you could scan over the text in mysql checking it against http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-html-translation-table.php -- I don't know that its any more or less safe using the normal html_entity_decode() without looking at the underlying C code though.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to, when you encode them and save them to DB, they will be shown on the web page (when you use echo $result['message'];) as they should. Browsers automaticaly decode them.

I am using this function to strip input:

```
function stripinput($text) {
    if (!is_array($text)) {
        $text = trim($text);
        $text = preg_replace("/(&amp;)+(?=\#([0-9]{2,3});)/i", "&", $text);
        $search = array("&", "\"", "'", "\\", '\"', "\'", "<", ">", "&nbsp;");
        $replace = array("&amp;", "&quot;", "&#39;", "&#92;", "&quot;", "&#39;", "&lt;", "&gt;", " ");
        $text = str_replace($search, $replace, $text);
    }else{
        foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
            $text[$key] = stripinput($value);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```