# How can I escape URL parameter for using it into the query?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo

I have a function which generates a query. Something like this:

```
// this is a simplified version of my real code
public function get_query(){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    return "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = $name";
}
```

As you know, such queries aren't safe. Because they are threatened by SQL injection. Anyway, I need to *escape* `$name` variable before using it into the query.

Well there are two approaches: *(since I use PDO. Otherwise there is also an old way which is using `mysql_escape_string()`)*

1. Using `PDO::prepare()`
2. Using `PDO::quote()`

Both of them need the PDO connection which isn't access into the generator query function. Now I want to know, is there any other approach?

Comment: using pdo you can use param  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge I don't want to pass parameter like `?` or`:param` in the query. I just want to make a query as string.

Comment: If you have PDO use it...

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162491/alternative-to-mysql-real-escape-string-without-connecting-to-db

Comment: it is impossible to safely escape a string without a DB connection.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You could have the function return something that will **later** be used with PDO. Since you said it's not available in generation time, do any step needed beforehand, then use PDO, because well, you'll have to, some time.

Where PDO is **not available**:

```
public function get_query(){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    return array(
        'query' => 'SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :name',
        'params' => array(':name', $name)
    );
}
```

Where PDO **is available**:

```
// pass '$values' to a class where a connection is available
$values = get_query();
$pdo->prepare($values['query']); // $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE name = :name');
$pdo->execute($values['params']); // $pdo->execute(array(':name', value_of_$name));
```

It would look like the [Second Example from the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php#refsect1-pdostatement.execute-examples). It will allow you to still use prepared statements with parameterized queries, even without knowing what query / parameters are being used.

---

**Some notes:**

- [Escaping is **not enough**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) to [prevent sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php);
- This won't change much of your original idea, since you'd still pass to PDO the generated query returned from `get_query()`;
- In case your query generation is too complex, you could just use `?` in the query as unnamed parameters - similar to example 3 from the manual - provided the values are passed in the correct order.